# Searching a CSV file repeat error

Tags: python, csv, python-3.3, opencsv

I am searching a csv file using the month in the date:

```
Jackson,Samantha,2 Heather Row,Basingstoke,RG21 3SD,01256 135434,23/04/1973,sam.jackson@hotmail.com
Vickers,Jonathan,18 Saville Gardens,Reading,RG3 5FH,01196 678254,04/02/1965,the_man@btinternet.com
Morris,Sally,The Old Lodge, Hook,RG23 5RD,01256 728443,19/02/1975,smorris@fgh.co.uk
Cobbly,Harry,345 The High Street,Guildford,GU2 4KJ,01458 288763,30/03/1960,harry.cobbly@somewhere.org.uk
Khan,Jasmine,36 Hever Avenue,Edenbridge,TN34 4FG,01569 276524,28/02/1980,jas.khan@hotmail.com
Vickers,Harriet,45 Sage Gardens,Brighton,BN3 2FG,01675 662554,04/04/1968,harriet.vickers@btinternet.com
```

There are a few problems such as; not displaying all of the relevant people, when it is retried it does not work and produces an error:

```
   1. Surname
2. D.O.B
3. Quit
Please select an option: 2
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 12
Month not found.
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 02
Month not found.
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 02
Month not found.
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 03
Month not found.
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 12
Month not found.
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 01
Month not found.
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 
Must be a number
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 04
Month not found.
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 50
Must be 1-12
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02:
```

Here is the code:

```
def input_month():
    addrsBk
    while True:
        try:
            month = int(input("Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Must be a number")
        else:
            if month in range(1, 13):
                return month
            print("Must be 1-12")



def DOB_search(BkRdr):
    addrsBk
    while True:
        search_month = input_month()
        addrsBk
        for row in BkRdr:
            DOB = row[6]
            day,month,year = DOB.split("/")
            if search_month == int(month): 
                surname = row[0]
                firstname = row[1]
                print(firstname, " ",surname)
                return"".join((firstname, surname))
                addrsBk.close
        print("Month not found.")
```

Comment: Why does your code check a range of 1-13 but the comment says 1-12? Why do you take DOB as row[6] when it clearly isn't the 6th field?

Comment: 1. Surname
2. D.O.B
3. Quit
Please select an option: 2
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02: 13
Must be 1-12
Please enter the birth month in a two digit format e.g. 02:

Comment: it is the seventh item and python starts at 0 so 6 is the 'python' csv row

Comment: Where are the code that generates this output: `That was an incorrect option, please try again:` ?

Comment: @Trimax sorry i belive that was an error please see the update!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is that the first time `for row in BkRdr:` is executed, the file is exhaust, the pointer is EOF (End Of File) and there aren't more lines to read.  Then, the second time it's goes across the `for row in BkRdr:` no more blocks are executed.

To solve this, you must take the file pointer to the start of the file with the `.seek(0)` atribute.

If you has opened the csv file like this:

```
myFile = open('file_01.csv', mode='r')
BkRdr = csv.reader(myFile, delimiter=',')
```

you can fix your code with:

```
for row in BkRdr:
    DOB = row[6]
    day,month,year = DOB.split("/")
    if search_month == int(month): 
        surname = row[0]
        firstname = row[1]
        print(firstname, " ",surname)
        return"".join((firstname, surname))
        addrsBk.close
print("Month not found.")
myFile.seek(0)
```

`<file>.seek(int)` put the file line pointer to the position of `int` number, in this case to the beginning of the file (BOF).

In every case, this isn't a issue of csv file, it is of the file object. You can read this:

[Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)